# How to configure karma-runner (also known as testacular) to work with closure-library

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, google-closure, google-closure-library, karma-runner

I'm trying to use karma-runner with mocha testing framework to test an application built with closure-library and angularjs.

I always get `namespace.Application is not defined`

thanks in advance.

here's my config file

```
basePath = '';

files = [
  MOCHA,
  MOCHA_ADAPTER,
  {pattern: 'vendors/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'public/javascripts/deps.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/expect.js/expect.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true},
  {pattern: 'public/javascripts/*.js', watched: true, included: false, served: true},
  {pattern: 'tests/*.test.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true}
];
exclude = [
];
reporters = ['progress'];
port = 9876;
runnerPort = 9100;
colors = true;
logLevel = LOG_INFO;
autoWatch = true;
browsers = ['Chrome', 'Firefox'];
captureTimeout = 60000;
singleRun = false;
```

and here's a simple test file

```
goog.require('namespace.Application');

describe('some sample', function() {
    it('should do something', function(done){
        console.log('asdasd', reAdoptAHydrant);
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I found out my problem using the dev console in Chrome. In my app, I server the public folder as the root. To access `/public/javascripts/whatever.js` from the browser I do `/javascripts/whatever.js`. So the problem was the compilation of the deps file. I needed to re-compile it so it can follow the "new" location of the files `/public/javscripts/whatever.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [repo](https://github.com/vojtajina/closure-deps-resolver) has some pointers in setting up Google closure with karma testrunner.

Comment: I found this repo too, but it use the canary version of karma-runner and it seems like there is a lot changes in the config file.

Comment: After a bit of digging in that repo and lots of head bashing, I've gotten karma + closure working for me. I'm kinda new to node, but running these commands and updating my config to sample one in the above repo helped: npm install -g karma@canary, npm install -g karma-phantomjs-browser. Then, I had to clone https://github.com/vojtajina/closure-deps-resolver locally and run npm install -g in root as I couldn't find on npm registry.

Comment: I gisted my config if it helps: https://gist.github.com/rbarreca/054597e602cf58324e40

Comment: Oh, and I realize now you can do `npm install -g git+https://github.com/vojtajina/closure-deps-resolver.git` no need clone.

Comment: I guess the would be better to migrate from 0.8.x to 0.9.x even though it's not published yet on npm. But I managed to make it work.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered since I should probably use the latest version.

Comment: Guys, I just added some readme, setup travis build and pushed the karma-closure plugin to NPM...